# Problem when setting Scala(metals) in VScode

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code

The first time, i code Scala in VScode. I setting extension Scala( metal) and i have problem when automatic build import
Warning: Automaticc build import is not support for sbt . To fix this problem, upgrade to sbt 0.13.17 
( i updated the newest version of sbt)

Comment: Which version of sbt you have?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok does VScode and  metals require sbt or they can work with maven as well

Comment: Scala Metals require BSP configuration generated. VSCode can detect sbt and ask it to generate such configuration, but it can also be generated by Scala CLI or Mill. I do not know whether Maven have plugins with such functionality but [this Giter8](https://github.com/scalameta/maven-scala-seed.g8) template suggest so.

Answer (score 0):

For me it said I should update to `1.2.8`.

I changed `version` in my `build.sbt` file to:

`version := "1.2.8"`

Then I ran: `sbt run`.